# excel vba method range of object _worksheet failed

Tags: vba, excel

can anyone help me fix my code? it says "method range of object _worksheet failed" but I can't find what's wrong with it.

I just mashed up a couple of codes to make this before and it worked nicely but now I can't find the error.

what this code does is open the file where it would want to copy the first sheet, put it in the workbook i'm using before the worksheet "Main Page", and it pastes everything to the bottom of the worksheet "BOM-DB" and then it deletes that worksheet and closes the workbook it got it from.

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
Dim FileName As String, FileToOpen As String

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Choose Excel File to Import", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xl?? (*.xl??),")
If FileToOpen = "False" Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Exit Sub
Else
Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileToOpen)

wbk2.Sheets.Copy before:=Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Sheets("Main Page")

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
Dim ws1LR As Long, ws2LR As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets("BOM-DB")

ws1LR = ws1.Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws2LR = ws2.Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2
k = ws2LR
Do Until i = ws1LR
    With ws1
        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 27)).Copy
    End With

    With ws2
        .Cells(k, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End With

    k = k + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop
wbk2.Close
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

the excel file its always getting from ranges from A to AA.

Comment: Which line generates the error...

Comment: it says there is an error on `.Cells(k, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in your code as seen below:

**Edit1:** Explicitly declare *After Argument*

```
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim FileToOpen As String

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Choose Excel File to Import", _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xl?? (*.xl??),")
If FileToOpen = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wbk1 = Thisworkbook: Set ws1 = wbk1.Sheets("BOM-DB")
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileToOpen)
    DoEvents
    Set ws2 = wbk2.Sheets(1) '~~> I assume you have only 1 sheet?

    With ws2
        .Range("A2", .Range("AA" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
        ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Range("A:A").Find("*", ws1.Range("A1") _
            , , , , xlPrevious).Row).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End If
wbk2.Close False
```

Is this what you're trying. HTH.

Comment: i'm confused. it looks correct but what it does is opens the workbook, closes it, then selects the range A to AA on the worksheet BOM-DB. and sorry I forgot to mention that it pastes within a table if that would matter.

Comment: @Hush00 I uncommented the `DoEvents`. It should copy and paste not unless you have more than one sheet in your source workbook.

Comment: oh. now I see. umm. wbk1 and wbk 2 are interchanged. I want to copy from the file I opened to the file i'm currently using but when I interchange wbk1 and wbk2 as `Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileToOpen)` and
    `Set wbk2 = Thisworkbook: Set ws1 = wbk1.Sheets("BOM-DB")` it sends an error

Comment: @Hush00 Sorry mybad. It should be `With ws2`. :p See my edit. ws1 and ws2 interchanged. Again silly mistake. Apologies.

Comment: thanks a lot! been trying to fix this for a couple of days now. :)

Comment: @Hush00 Yeah, it'd be perfect if we could've spotted the cause of error, but sometimes it is easier to simplify a code rather than finding the error and make it work.

Comment: umm. sorry but could you help me with another error? **method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Range' failed**. i'm pretty sure this has something to to with the table where it's being pasted but I've had problems like this before and don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: @Hush00 Did it work or it did not? I mean, when you accepted the answer have you tried it and it worked and then now for some reason it generates another error or does it error out on the first try?

Comment: it worked. I see the pasted values in the table behind the error then excel suddenly crashes. sorry.

Comment: @Hush00 And the data append to the table? How large is your data? I mean how many rows. Does the table have formulas?

Comment: no formulas. the data is usually 300 to 2000 rows of data.

Comment: @Hush00 But the data appends to the table, just errors out after the process?

Comment: @Hush00 That is strange. But try my edit. Maybe the `[AA1]` is causing the fuss. Not sure though. I simulated it at my end and it works without crashing excel.

Comment: when I extend the table where the pasted values can fit, it works fine. but when I leave it where there are values on the last row of the table, that's where there is an error and excel crashes. so i'm pretty sure now that it's the table thats causing the errors.

Comment: @Hush00 Ah. Which column dictates the last row of the table. In current code, we based it on Column AA as I patterned in your sample code. You only need to change it to whatever column that dictates the last row.

Comment: oh. i'm sorry. it's based on Column A. I forgot to change that in my sample code.

Comment: @Hush00 Ok see my edit. Hope we nail it down now. :)

Comment: yay. no more error, and no more crashing. thanks a lot. :) thanks for your patience with me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error, but if I'm not mistaken, the `PasteSpecial` method without any additional arguments is essentially just pasting *values only*.  If that is acceptable, then this will save you a few lines of code and should hopefully avoid the error:

Instead of:

```
With ws1
    .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 27)).Copy
End With

With ws2
    .Cells(k, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
End With
```

Do this:

```
With ws1
    ws2.Cells(k+1, 1).Resize(1,27).Value = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 27)).Value
End With
```

Comment: excel just hung up. and sorry I forgot to say that it pastes within a table so maybe that contributes to the error.